# Contains references to object definitions that could not be found

Tags: vba, excel

ActiveX command buttons on workbook stopped working all of sudden. To fix this I  deleted all the exd  files but still no luck. I then deleted the command button from sheet, deleted all cells (Ctrl + A  --> Delete), removed the procedures defined on the sheet and trying to run a simple test proc.  I am still getting the compile error (image 1), however I have noticed the proc which I deleted from sheet4 code section 'GetAccoutCodes' appears in object browser although there is no such procedure (image 2). How do I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you restart Excel in between applying these fixes?

Comment: I have restarted excel  & PC, cleared temp memory using ccleaner.

Comment: Was Excel closed when you deleted the .exd files?

Comment: Yes,  deleted using command prompt

Comment: Try in the immediate window `thisworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("GetAccountCodes").remove`

Comment: I just read in "Office Watch" that a recent UPDATE has broken this. "The company has managed to break one of their own VBA controls, used by third-party Office developers. The control  mscomctl.ocx   (version 6.01.9846) can cause the error “Object doesn't support this property or method”... The cause appears to be updates for Office 2016/2013 and 2010. KB2920727 , KB3039794 , KB2881029 for 32-bit releases." http://new.office-watch.com/2016/vba-bug-caused-by-office-updates/